# Why LuaLaTeX adds features (like rot13) into any OpenType font in cache

Tags: fonts, luatex, opentype, substitution

The following program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{Erewhon-regular.otf}

Hello {\addfontfeature{RawFeature={rot13,!!??}} World !?}
 {\addfontfeature{RawFeature={rot13,!!??}}Hello} World !?

\end{document}
```

gives the following output:

```
Hello Jbeyq ‽ Uryyb World !?
```

rot13 swaps circularly letters (it is the Caesar crypting method) and !!?? substitutes the two signs ? and ! by the superposed one.

These features are not in the genuine Erewhon-regular.otf file and I assume they are added by LuaLaTeX when creating the lua version of the font in  /Users/.../Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var/luatex-cache/.
Is it right?

Why these features are added?

Any other one?

Note that this occurs for any OTF font (even with fonts that are not in the TeXLive).

Thanks a lot for explanations.

Comment: The code for this is in [the `luaoftload` source](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/blob/79fb28b633691fc7349e1d833317049ba9954e80/src/luaotfload-features.lua#L617-L638). There's obviously no practical use for this; I'm guessing that it's there to help with testing the feature code.

Comment: Why-type questions are generally off-topic for this site as they call for speculation that’s rarely supported by evidence. Such questions should be directed to the author(s) and maintainer(s) of the program or package in question.